# Catkin and CMake integration question for cross-compilation ROS node

Tags: cmake, catkin

Trying to cross-compile a ros node which relays on some arm64 libraries located in a different path other than /usr/lib/arm64-

Error received is:

```
Errors     << gps_confidence_module:make /gitlab/soads-ros/DAS/ros/logs/gps_confidence_module/build.make.013.log                                                        
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so.0.4', needed by '/gitlab/soads-ros/DAS/ros/devel/.private/gps_confidence_module/lib/gps_confidence_module/gps_confidence_module'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gps_confidence_module.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
cd /gitlab/soads-ros/DAS/ros/build/gps_confidence_module; catkin build --get-env gps_confidence_module | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
.....................................................................................................................................................................................
```

The error goes away when I add the path inside the CMakelist.txt with:

```
link_directories(
        ${PDK_PATH}/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
)
```

Is there a way to make this `link_directories` global to my catkin environment?

trying to avoid to insert the `link_directories` code on every single CMakelists.txt of my ROS source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in your CMakeLists.txt files yourself. This kind of info should go into your toolchain file (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

I haven't worked with your kind of setup, but setting [`CMAKE_SYSROOT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) should work in your case.

toolchain-arm64.cmake

```
set(PDK_PATH ...)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME ...)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm64)

set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /path/to/c++/compiler)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/c/compiler)
 
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${PDK_PATH}/targetfs")

...

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```